# Film with a hero whose memories of last years are erased

Tags: identify-this-movie

There is a film that my friend saw 10 years ago, but remembers only the plot. Is there anyone who knows what film is he talking about? Here is the plot.

The film is about a man, who doesn't remember the last years of his life. He lives with his wife and boy, his father lives separately. He is doing a reconstruction of planes, and his family is telling him that previously he was a plane pilot, but now he can not continue with his previous profession. By that time, he also attends one doctor for treatment and is taking some tablets, and the doctor is saying to him that the tablets will help him bring back his memories.

One day, some man comes to our hero and tells him that they have worked together previously and now they are both in danger. After a few days he finds, that man is dead. At the end, he understands that he and his wife have worked as a hired killer and after he failed with his last job, the company decided to erase his last year's memory (it's not Bourne Identity :) and also his father is actually just playing that role but is not actually his father.

I believe this film should be the release of 90's or early 00's. Can anyone help me find any information about this film?

Comment: Country of origin?  Any actors/actresses you remember?

Comment: Should be a Hollywood movie, but he doesn't remember any actors.

Comment: It's a long shot but there's a similar movie i watched a long time ago,  "Fugitive Mind".  Here's the trailer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTDyULQ-KT8

Comment: You can't remember a movie about someone's memory being erased, you've got to love the irony :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I got it: [Traitor's Heart](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0171841/combined) from 1999. From IMDb:

> **Nick Brody (Bryan Genesse), has been suffering from amnesia for five years. Nevertheless, he has a beautiful wife (Kimberly Kates) and an adoring son** who love him very much. While they are watching a fireworks display in New York City, their son wanders away, and they search frantically for him. Nick finds him and **runs into a man who says that he knows him.** Grateful for the man's help in finding his son, Nick gives the guy his phone number and promises to buy him a beer. The next day a different guy calls and warns Nick that he must meet him or bad things will happen. **Nick backs out of a fishing trip with his father and goes to his workplace where he earns his paycheck by working on helicopters.** The guy from the phone conversation shows up. Nick ignores most of what the guy says until the guy shows him a photograph of the helicopter crash that Nick survived. Now Nick has second thoughts about how he could have survived such a devastating crash. At that point, just as this stranger has gained a modicum of credibility in our hero's eyes, a helicopter hovers overhead and gunmen start firing bullets at them. **The stranger scrambles onto his bus to drive away, only to catch a bullet in the back** and crash into a couple of parked planes. A massive fireball inferno destroys the guy and the cops treat Nick like an idiot. Nick wonders now if he were in the army, but his wife claims that he wasn't. Even Nick's creepy therapist tries to convince Nick otherwise. Eventually, **Nick discovers that he was an elite military assassin and that the military tried to wash their hands of him.**

His wife and dad turn out to be part of the conspiracy. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Only 173 votes in imdb and you managed to find it! Just wow!!! I don't know how did you find it, but many thanks from my friend :)

Comment: No problem. :) A matter of luck and the right set of keywords, I guess. I haven't heard of this film before and was lucky enough to stumble on such a detailed IMDb review. [Not that this was easy - I must have gone through a dozen obscure movies with similar plots. There are *so* many movies that ripped off Total Recall\Philip K. Dick... ;)] Glad your friend found it at last and thanks for approving!

Answer (score 1):

I saw it a long time ago and I don't remember if all the details fit, but the company erasing the protagonist's memories reminds me of the movie [Cypher (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_%28film%29). From IMDb:

> Hoping for a more exciting life than the suburban drawl he currently inhabits, nerdy salary man Morgan Sullivan takes a job as an industrial spy at Digicorp, a global computer corporation. Digicorp assigns him the duty of flying to various conventions around America, recording the speeches that are made. But when Sullivan meets a mysterious woman he begins to realize that his job may not be what it seems, as he descends into a dark underworld of brainwashing and struggles to maintain his own identity.

Comment: No problem. It's always best to add a few things to the answer like a synopsis, year, actors, clips etc. No idea if this is right answer, but there are definitely some similarities. +1

Comment: @ElectricSid, why do you think that this is the movie I described? I looked to the plot and don't find anything about constructing of planes, erased memory, etc. (btw, have not asked my friend about this movie yet).

Comment: @mesiesta There's *definitely* memory wipes, I'm pretty sure the whole plot revolves around it. A planted wife and designing helicopters(?) also figure into the plot.

Comment: @Walt, in my scenario hero should be with erased memory the most part of the movie (or at least half). I'm pretty sure, that this is something else.

Comment: No, my friend confirmed that this is not the movie he is searching

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but could it be [History of Violence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399146/)?

> When a pair of petty criminals attempt to rob his small-town diner, Tom Stall (Viggo Mortensen) quickly and easily kills them both. In the flush of news coverage of Tom's seemingly heroic actions, a threatening stranger named Carl Fogarty (Ed Harris) comes to town, fingering the unassuming family man as long-missing Philadelphia mobster Joey Cusack. To the horror of his wife, Edie (Maria Bello), and teenage son, Jack (Ashton Holmes), Tom finds he must confront his violent past.

I cannot recall the scene with the planes as it has been a while since I watched however, he runs a business and two people try to hurt one of the waitresses and he protects her but ends up killing the two criminals.

Then another person arrives claiming that the hero used to be a professional killer is the past?

Comment: Someone too suggested me this movie, but this is not the one I am searching :(

Comment: No problem hope you find it!

Comment: History of Violence is about someone hiding his criminal past from his family, but they are his real family and he don't have amnesia